# Custom columns on a strongly typed DataTable

Tags: strongly-typed-dataset

I am using typed datasets to retrieve and manipulate data. To generate a typed dataset I use the built-in dataset designer and drag-drop tables from data sources. In addition, mostly I need to add custom columns to my data tables.

The problem is that when I make a change in the underlying database schema I simply delete and regenerate the data table and loose all the custom columns that I added earlier. So everytime I regenerate a data table I had to add these custom columns again and again.

So my question is that if there is an easy way to mantain or keep track of these custom columns?

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete the DataTable and regenerate it. Instead right-click, choose configure and adjust the query to add/remove your new columns. Then click finish and the table will be updated in the DataSet but without deleting your customisations.

Comment: This is a good idea, but seems as hard as maintaining the custom columns.

Comment: Just try it. You only need to click on a checkbox.